# How can I disable the Alt+` (backtick) key combination

Tags: shortcut-keys

I was wondering if there was anyway to disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> key combination that switches the windows of a program.

I've tried going through CompizConfig and disabling the Switcher there with no luck. I've even disabled every single key combination in dconf-editor in the keybinding category to no avail. Help would be greatly appreciated.